# Differences between PostMapping and DeleteMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, checkmarx

I am getting HRA_JAVA_Spring_Boot_Misconfiguration_Actuator_Endpoint_Security_Disabled from checkmarx scan.
the detail says, Exposure of system data to an unauthorized control sphere
Description summary: exposing system data or debugging information helps an adversary learn about the system and form an attack plan...
the example includes code printing an exception to the standard error stream.

I have similar code pattern for postMapping and DeleteMapping meaning that the request and response format are same. business logic is slightly different.

```
@ApiOperation(value="delete task", response=Response.class)
@ApiResponses(value =...)
@DeleteMapping(value="/delete/task", produces="application.json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteTask(@RequestHeader(value="header1") @size(min=10, max=10) String requestId, HttpServletResponse httpResponse){
  Response response = new Response();
  return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
}
```

checkmarx scan goes well if I switch from @DeleteMapping to @PostMapping. Can someone please explain what is the difference between @PostMapping and @DeleteMapping from this checkmarx scan perspective?

Thanks,

Comment: this Checkmarx query (HRA_JAVA_Spring_Boot_Misconfiguration_Actuator_Endpoint_Security_Disabled) doesn't seem to be part of the standard queries they ship in their product. What version of Checkmarx are you using? I am assuming this could be a custom Checkmarx query that your security team have wrote so you might want to ask them exactly how this can be remediated